# How do I prevent the repetition of a success alert in this Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have made a **[blogging application in Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)**.

I am working on the functionality of *adding comment replies*.

In the controller, I add comments like this:

```
$comment = [
  'user_id'    => Auth::user()->id,
  'article_id' => $request->get( 'article_id' ),
  'parent_id' => $request->get( 'parent_id' ),
  'body'       => $fields['msg'],
  'approved'   => 0
];

// Insert comment in the 'comments' table
$query = Comment::create( $comment );

if ( $query ) {
  return redirect()->back()->with( 'success', 'Your comment is pending.' );
} else {
  return redirect()->back()->with( 'error', 'Adding comment failed' );
}
```

I have added the comments form under each comment:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
  @if (null == $comment->parent_id)
    <li class="depth-1 comment">
      <div class="comment__avatar">
          <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}" alt="<img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}" alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}" width="50" height="50">" width="50" height="50">
      </div>
      <div class="comment__content">
          <div class="comment__info">
              <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
              <div class="comment__meta">
                  <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
                  @auth
                    <div class="comment__reply">
                      <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
                    </div>
                  @endauth
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="comment__text">
              <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      // Comments form template here!
      @auth
        <div class="comment__reply">
          <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">Reply</a>
        </div>
      @endauth

      {{-- Comment replies --}}
      @if (count($comment->replies))
        <ul class="children">
          @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
            <li class="depth-2 comment">
              <div class="comment__avatar">
                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
              </div>
              <div class="comment__content">
                  <div class="comment__info">
                      <div class="comment__author">{{ $reply->user->first_name }} {{ $reply->user->last_name }}</div>
                      <div class="comment__meta">
                          <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($reply->created_at)) }}</div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="comment__text">
                    <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      @endif
    </li>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

The comments form (`partials\comment-form.blade.php`):

```
@if (session('success'))
    @include('themes/' .$theme_directory . '/partials/success')
@endif

@if (session('error'))
    @include('themes/' .$theme_directory . '/partials/errors')
@endif

<form method="post" action="{{ route('comment.submit') }}" autocomplete="off">
  @csrf
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ $article->id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}">

        <div class="message form-field">
            <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

            @error('msg')
            <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

#### The problem

Due to the fact that the comments form template contains the success (or failure) alert inside it (the template) lives within the `@foreach` that loops comments when a reply is added, the confirmation alert appears under every comment.

Of course, I want it to appear **only under the comment to which a reply was given**.

[image]

#### How can I achieve the desired result?

#### NOTE

While trying to implement the solution proposed by @Alun Razvan, I get the error `Undefined variable: comment` in comment-form.blade.php.

Comment: You've been editing your question and removed 

          // Comments form template here!
          @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')

how would you expect others to follow your question properly ? ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, also pass the parent comment ID like this:

```php
return redirect()->back()->with([
    'success' => 'Your comment is pending.',
    'success_comment_id' => $request->get('parent_id'),
]);
```

Then in your `comment-form.blade.php` template, check if the comment IDs match.

```php
@if (session('success') && session('success_comment_id') == ($comment->id ?? null))
    @include('themes/' .$theme_directory . '/partials/success')
@endif
```